# Aerial photogrammetry book with all the math

Tags: mathematics, photogrammetry, references

Can anyone recommend a book that hits all the math for the general situation of doing serious photogrammetry calculations on aerial photographs?

Particularly an inexpensive book or one I can get very cheaply used, as my budget is quite constrained.

I am a mathematician. I am working on an aerial photogrammetry project which includes making corrections as finely as possible. I need a book that covers the general situation with all the necessary mathematics to do actual computations, particularly serious mathematical discussions of atmospheric refraction correction and radial lens correction, .... simple stuff like triangulating a point I can do myself.

I want a serious book because after significant searching I have found that free or online resources on the topic fall into two camps:

1) scholarly articles of current research that involve specialized methods that are not what I am after - I want the general big picture described precisely, not an article that takes 2 hours to read only to discover that it is only useful if you used their special calibration technique.

2) Books and summaries that that contain equations that are thrown in, but are not expected to be used and probably weren't used by the author, e.g. contradictory equations, undefined constants, variables that are defined but don't show up in the equations, etc.... These tend to **look** like they have the math, but were clearly not written with the idea that math would need to actually need to be used by the reader. For instance I have two free sources with radial correction equations, but they contradict each other, reversing the undistorted and the distorted x and y. I don't know which is really correct.

I have found that there are a number of photogrammetry books that have a sprinkling of formulas to seem more technical, but not what you would really need.

Comment: Have you looked at any books that include Moffitt or Mikhail as authors?

Comment: Elements of Photogrammetry with Application in GIS, Fourth Edition http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Photogrammetry-Application-Fourth-Edition/dp/0071761128

Comment: I am looking into the suggested books, but am waiting to accept an answer until I have looked at them. I have ordered older versions of two of the suggested books.

Comment: The Moffit and Mikhail book had very little useful math. Maybe I didn't get the right one.

Comment: @Mapperz An older edition of the book you suggested is the one I have found best so far from the suggestions (older edition to keep the cost way down). If you post your proposal as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introduction_to_Modern_Photogrammetry.html?id=JdNTAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y is an other good option. Clear and simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*Analytical Photogrammetry*, 2nd edition, by Sanjib Kumar Ghosh. Pergamon Press, 1988. (ISBN 008036103X) I used to own the 1st edition, 1979 -- very mathematical is was.

There's a newer book, *Fundamentals Of Computational Photogrammetry*, also by Sanjib Kumar Ghosh. Concept Publishing, 2005. (ISBN: 818069187X) Maybe it amounts to a 3rd edition of *Analytical...*?